# What happens when the wait method is called inside the method of an object?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking

I have method like the following in the main thread, that invokes a method on my data structure as follows -:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

data_structure_object.insert(value);
}
```

and I am using a ReadWrite object call it rwLock inside the data structure class that is used to prevent thread interference, the Read Write class looks like the following -:

```
public class ReadWriteLocks {

    // these 3 variables help in creating a read write lock
    private int numberOfReaders = 0;
    private int numberOfWriters = 0;
    private int numberOfWriteRequests = 0;

    // getter method for the number of readers
    public int getNumberOfReaders() {
        return this.numberOfReaders;
    }

    // getter method for the number of writers
    public int getNumberOfWriters() {
        return this.numberOfWriters;
    }

    // getter method for the number of write requests
    public int getNumberOfWriteRequests() {
        return this.numberOfWriteRequests;
    }

    // this function checks if a thread can acquire the lock
    public synchronized void lockRead() throws InterruptedException {

        while (numberOfWriters > 0 || numberOfWriteRequests > 0)
            this.wait();
    }

    // this function unlocks a lock occupied by a reader thread
    public synchronized void unlockRead() {

        // decrement the number of readers
        --numberOfReaders;
        notifyAll();
    }

    // this function checks if a thread can acquire the write lock
    public synchronized void lockWrite() throws InterruptedException {

        // increase the number of write requests
        ++numberOfWriteRequests;

        while (numberOfReaders > 0 || numberOfWriters > 0)
            this.wait();

        --numberOfWriteRequests;
        ++numberOfWriters;
    }

    // this function is used to take a thread away from the lock
    public synchronized void unlockWrite() {

        // decrement the number of writers
        --numberOfWriters;

        // notify all the threads
        this.notifyAll();
    }

}
```

and inside the insert method of the data structure, I include the following code snippet

```
// acquire the read/write lock
        try {
            rwLock.lockRead();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Some operation

        // release the lock
        rwLock.unlockRead();
```

The question is, Is this a valid way of ensuring fairness and also locking threads so as to maintain the data structure consistency? also besides all this I am not able to figure out how shall I provide the following functionality -: "Allowing multiple Readers to acquire the lock and reading the data till there is no writer requesting or writing to the resource" , I am pretty confused about the situation kindly help.

Comment: Any reasons why you try to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I am not trying to reinvent the wheel, but this is something for my own understanding.

Comment: There is a [ReadWriteLock in the JDK with a fairness option](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html). One issue with your code (there might be others) is that a thread that does not hold a lock could call unlock and allow several writers to run in parallel for example. Also you should always call unlock in a finally block: if your code throws an exception the lock will be held forever.

Comment: Are there any other issues you can spot with this, but how do I allow multiple readers to acquire the lock in case there is no writer present currently.

Comment: Yes my mistake but a thread could unlock another thread which is a problem (when you lock, you don't really know if you hold the lock as another thread might have unlocked it).

Comment: @assylias : I actually need to implement the read/write lock on a circular double linked list, where multiple readers could acquire the lock as long as there is no write being performed or no write requests up, but I am finding problem to tackle this case

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37760/discussion-between-ankitsablok-and-assylias)

Comment: I'm on my mobile so won't be very convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that you are attempting to duplicate a perfectly good existing `ReadWriteLock` posing as a `ReentrantReadWriteLock` there are two certain issues in your code:

1. Your instance variables should be `volatile`.

   ```
   private volatile int numberOfReaders = 0;
   private volatile int numberOfWriters = 0;
   private volatile int numberOfWriteRequests = 0;
   ```
2. You need to be careful with your transition from lock-requested to locked.

   ```
   --numberOfWriteRequests;
   ++numberOfWriters;
   ```

probably should be

```
    ++numberOfWriters;
    --numberOfWriteRequests;
```

because there could be a moment between those two instructions when `numberOfWriteRequests` is zero and `numberOfWriters` is zero. This would let your spin loop in `lockRead` out and things would break ... sometimes.

You would probably be best to get this moved to code review.